# How can I inject dependencies in a service using Dagger2

Tags: android, mobile, service, dependency-injection

I have an alarmManager in a activity that starts a service. I want to get a instance of my presenter my service. I have used Dagger 2 in my project to handle dependency injection. Here is my code:

my activity where I start/kill my service every hour:

```
public class ActionsActivity extends ActivityBase {

    @Inject
    ActionsActivityPresenter mPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actions);

    ((App)getApplication()).getMyComponent()
    .plus(new ActionsActivityModule()).inject(this);
    ..........
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventsService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),minuteInMillies * 60, pendingIntent);
    ........
}
```

And here is my module:

```
@Module(includes = {ContextModule.class, ScannerActivityModule.class})
public class ActionsActivityModule {

.........

@AppScope
@Provides
public RemoveShiftEvent removeShiftEvent(ShiftEventDatabase shiftEventDatabase) {
    return new RemoveShiftEventImpla(shiftEventDatabase);
}

@AppScope
@Provides
public ActionsActivityPresenter actionsActivityPresenter(InsertShiftEvent insertShiftEvent, SendShiftEvent sendShiftEvent, RemoveShiftEvent removeShiftEvent, NameEncryptor nameEncryptor) {
    return new ActionsActivityPresenter(insertShiftEvent, sendShiftEvent, removeShiftEvent, nameEncryptor);
}
......

}
```

and finally my service where nothing is happening at the moment

```
public class EventsService extends Service {

public EventsService() {
}

private ActionsActivityPresenter actionsActivityPresenter;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Timber.d( "onStartCommand Service has started");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

My question is, is there a way to inject my ActionsActivityPresenter in my service using the dagger framework? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use injector in Service like Activity/Fragment injector

```
@Module(includes = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuilderModule::class, ServiceBuilderModule::classs])
abstract class ApplicationModule
{
    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindApplication(application: BeaverApplication): Application

    @Module
    companion object
    {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @ApplicationContext
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideApplicationContext(application: BeaverApplication): Context = application
    }
}
```

Like you "contribute injector" with activities/fragments, do the same for services :

```
@Module
abstract class ServiceBuilderModule
{
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeAuthenticatorService(): AuthenticatorService
}
```

You got a concrete example from my projet template [here](https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver) with the AuthenticatorService class

Comment: One more thing to add, extend the service with DaggerService to implement this.